# Terraform apply not saving data in the backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am running terraform apply while deploying the code. But having this error
`Failed to save state: consul CAS failed with transaction errors: [0xc0008ac480]

```
Error: Failed to persist state to backend.

The error shown above has prevented Terraform from writing the updated state
to the configured backend. To allow for recovery, the state has been written
to the file "errored.tfstate" in the current working directory.

Running "terraform apply" again at this point will create a forked state,
making it harder to recover.

To retry writing this state, use the following command:
    terraform state push errored.tfstate`
```

And when I ran the terraform apply 2nd time I see below errors

```
 Error: Creating CloudWatch Log Group failed: ResourceAlreadyExistsException: The specified log group already exists:  The CloudWatch Log Group '/aws/kinesisfirehose/test-cloudfront-wafv2-logs' already exists.



Error: Error creating IAM Role test-pvcapture-cloudfront-wafv2-firehose: EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name test-pvcapture-cloudfront-wafv2-firehose already exists.
    status code: 409, request id: 0fd8fda2-88fe-4860-ba22-951573f74268



Error: Error creating WAFv2 IPSet: WAFDuplicateItemException: AWS WAF couldn’t perform the operation because some resource in your request is a duplicate of an existing one.
```

Terraform Version that i am using:

```
terraform --version
Terraform v0.13.5
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.16.0
```

Comment: Please can you update the question with the version of Terraform you are using?

Comment: I have updated the version info in the question above. Thank you for responding!

Comment: The errors on the second run are not surprising at all. This is what the warning message from the first run warns against.

Comment: What is your `backend` configuration (obv. don't mention the credentials)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. Our backend was running out of memory space. We had to clear out space in the backend. After that I had to run 'terraform import' to manually add the resources to the backend file. Since the issue was also in production, we were not able to run 'terraform destroy'. That fixed my issue.

Thanks everyone!!